# Swiper JS Phonegap issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, swiper.js

i am working on a webapp working with Swiper JS for my image gallery. Without the usage of Phonegap it works fine, but using Phonegap the "slide" effect doenst work correctly and the prev/next Buttons of the JS were shown but they are not touchable. Curiously it starts working after changing the size of my browser window (firefox). Any ideas?

```
        <!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div id="swiper-wrapper" class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div id="img0" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img1" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img2" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img3" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img4" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img5" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img6" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img7" class="swiper-slide"></div>
            <div id="img8" class="swiper-slide"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Swiper JS -->
    <script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        spaceBetween: 30
    });
    </script>
```

The images are loaded via DOM

Answer (score 1):

i fixed the issue with the following solution:

loop through my images and add them into the swiper-wrapper:

```
var str = "<div class=swiper-slide><a href=data:iamge/png;base64,"+image_data+" data-lightbox="+image_id+" data-title="+image_date+" "+image_time+"><img src=data:image/png;base64,"+image_data+" class=gallery_images></img></a></div>";
$('.swiper-wrapper').append(str);
```

then intitiate the Swiper:

```
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    spaceBetween: 30
});
```

and after setting the divs attribute display:inherit i had to update the swiper object:

```
swiper.update(true);
```